# Clip polygon features with country boundary ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, intersection, clip

I am trying to trim the edges of some polygons based on a country boundary. I have tried both clip and intersect, but neither seem to be doing what I want. Below is the image I am working with. When I use clip and intersect, I only get the purple polygon returned. Should it not trim the edges of the other polygons to inside the country boundary, or am I using the wrong tool?[image: Clip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the purple polygon selected when you perform the clip it will only output the selected polygon.Deselect all the features you plan on clipping and try the clip again. That should clip everything to the larger polygon.

Comment: Dang it....That was slid off the visual part of the page when I ran the tool and I thought I had selected that polygon afterwards... Face palm again. Thanks cl3